# new WP_query > displays posts only once instead of running through full array

Tags: custom-post-types, query

we added a custom query to our template which works fine. So we want to display all posts out of our array. But if we have some duplicate IDs in our array, WP ignores the duplicated IDs and shows every Posts->ID only once.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => "custom_posttyp",
'order_by' => 'post__in',
'post__in'  => $post_ids, // array with (208, 212, 218, 208, 212, 218)
);
```

So based on this example the while-func just renders 3 posts instead of 6 - we think because of duplicated IDs - but we sometimes have to render also 2 or 3 copies of one post if the array has IDs twice, three times etc.

Any Idea?
Ben

Comment: You're running a function to request data from the database, that data exists once and you can obviously not just tell it to gather an array containing the same data multiple times, that's not how it works.

If you need to output the same data twice just run your loop twice, although I can't think of a single reason why you would ever need to?

Comment: this would be mad - we are using custom post types to display a selection of different posts selected my a frontend-user... so therefore we want to display all posts rather they are included twice or six, seven or twenty times... the output is important to show the right selection of a user

Comment: "We want to display all posts" then request all posts. You're still not explaining why you would want to show identical posts multiple times from  1 query?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array of IDs and look for the corresponding post in your results to generate output with duplicate posts:

```
$post_ids = array( 208, 212, 218, 208, 212, 218 );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_posttyp',
    'order_by' => 'post__in',
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
);

$the_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $post_ids as $id ){
    foreach( $the_posts as $a_post ){
        if( $id == $a_post->ID ){
            echo get_the_title( $a_post );
        }
    }
}
```